# When can we get unbiased estimate given biased data?

Tags: sampling, estimators, unbiased-estimator, selection-bias

There was a recent ["hot take" tweet by Andrej Karpathy](https://twitter.com/karpathy/status/1528453604515778560) (without any comment or clarification from the author):

> real-world data distribution is ~N(0,1)
> good dataset is ~U(-2,2)

It provoked many reactions, but it also made me wonder *under what conditions can we get an unbiased estimate given a biased sample?* Let's make the problem general, we have a population of interest and we want to estimate some quantity of the population, but we take a biased sample from it. For example, as said by Karpathy, we ignore the tails of the distribution and oversample some regions of the distribution (so we get a uniform sample from the normal distribution). Let's also assume that our estimator *does not* have any access to sampling weights, so we cannot explicitly bias-correct it by re-weighting the observations. Under what general conditions would we be able to obtain an unbiased estimate?

I'm interested in formalizing it, because quite obviously "it depends", for example, the biased sample from the example above would not affect our estimate for the mean, but it would be useless for estimating the 99% percentile. Can we bound it somehow?

Comment: $\theta$ does not seem to be a parameter of the population or of the observations.  And getting an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ will depend on what it is (think mean and variance of an unknown distribution as an example).  If you know the exact distribution of the population, why would you need any data, good or bad?

Comment: @Henry I changed the wording it you find it more clear.

Comment: I think one will need some assumptions on how badly biased the data is. In general a biased sample could be any distribution which has support on (a subset of) the support of the true distribution. I don't know a reasonable way to quantify or limit that bias. In the worst case where we repeatedly sample a single point things could get very bad.

Comment: I am a bit confused about your requirement of "*our estimator does not have any access to sampling weights, so we cannot explicitly bias-correct it by re-weighting the observations*", while we usually do not have sampling weights indeed, can't we estimate (to various degrees of success) based on existing assumptions?

Comment: @usεr11852 I'm just saying that we are restricted from using sampling weights. The tweet doesn't say “take a biased sample and use bias correction”, but seems to say that we can get away with a biased sample or it is desired.

Comment: OK, then I am unimpressed by the statement a bit... and I say that because it is partially why people around "Ethical AI" are making a (deserved) fuss and shows why they have some grounds to say big boys like LeCun, AK, etc. are (at least unintentionally) fueling some of the problems. Yes, we use biased data for large ML models and then we say "bias sample, LOL, not a problem, DNN FTW" and then we say "Oh, snap, X group is grossly misclassified, not my bad, the data's fault."  * surprised AI Picatsu face *.

Comment: @usεr11852 that seems to be a point. Here I'm just curious about formalizing how bad it can get, or the other way around, how much we can get away with the approach. Obviously, it can get arbitrarily bad, but I'm curious if we can formalize it to get some informed bounds.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will trawl the Internet later on this. I somehow suspect that this might be related to the concentration of measure but maybe I am miles off.

Comment: Tweets like this are so obtuse as to be practically useless. LinkedIn is guilty as well; it's a lousy effort to establish oneself as a thought leader on social media. Andrej may have great chops - I don't know - but it doesn't take much knowledge or experience to fire off tweets like this (and pay a little extra to boost them).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure from the short tweet whether the same is meant but it may be a thought that I usually express as:

When we sample for some application task, we often have several different needs/purposes, that do not necessarily ask for the same experimental design: data that is application-representative may not have the most efficient design for training/fitting a predictive model for that application, and validation of that model may require yet another experimental design.

---

There is a situation that I quite frequently encounter:

I'm chemometrician and work a lot with spectroscopic data. When we built regression models for quantitative prediction, we may have an application situation where the property of interest has *some* (maybe normal, maybe whatever) distribution. Still we may prefer the training data for our predictive model to have a (roughly) uniform distribution over the relevant space. This is more efficient for our application purposes:

Consider here just classical least squares as model, and compare data that follows a) a normal distribution in y or b) a uniform distribution symmetric about the mean y of scenario a). Both have the same number of training cases. When we look at the prediction intervals of the corresponding models, the normally distributed training data leads to a model with narrow prediction intervals at the center, and wider prediction intervals at the tails. Part of this is because uncertainty is always higher at the boundary of the training data range, but the normal distribution compared to the uniform distribution has in addition lower sampling density in the tails. We may say, we prefer to oversample the tails in order to get roughly/almost equal predictive performance over pretty much the whole training range.

(Predictions outside the training range will at the very least be marked as such and not trusted at all.)

Here's an example: we were training a predictive model for caraway seed oil (2 analytes, PLS model, input data NIR spectra) for a caraway breeding program.
A large number of samples was measured with NIR, they were all to be predicted. A subset of given size (70 analyses, of which I "spent" a few on replicates in order to measure portion-to-portion uncertainty within the same genotype) was to be sent for reference analysis of the oil to generate y training data. We went with a 2 stage strategy: first a uniform sample in spectra space was chosen. From the results, a preliminary predictive model was build and all available samples predicted. Further samples for reference analysis were chosen in concentration space via the Kennard-Stone algorithm (initialized with the previous training samples), thus generating a roughly uniform distribution in concentration space.

One may want to go even further in this application: since the breeding program wants to increase oil content, they region of interest is the high concentration range (for both analytes). One may thus choose to oversample even more in that region: noone is really interested in knowing whether a particular sample has low or very low oil content. But low uncertainty in the higher concentrations would be of practical use.

In addition, we may design training experiments to deliberately vary some other influencing factors (e.g. temperature) in order to train more robust/rugged models. There, it's often hard to know what the distribution during the application measurements will be. I'd think normal distribution is an OK assumption, but not even the mean is known (somewhat above the temperature in the room where the instrument is placed). So instead, we specify a temperature range where the model is supposed to be used, and then would typically go for a uniform coverage of that range (and raise a warning/error if data outside this range is encountered).

---

One example where validation asks for a fundamentally different experimental design than training are one-class classifiers. They are trained with positive instances only. Consider food fraud or falsified pharmaceuticals as application examples. While the fact that you can never know whether the next negative case follows any known fraudulent procedure is a very good reason to set this up as a one-class classifier, for validation you'd still want to test all kinds of known (or thinkable) false products (and not lump them into one figure of merit, but report their performance separately).

Answer (score 2):

With Bayesian modeling you can directly model bias.  If the distribution of the bias is symmetric about zero the net effect is to widen uncertainty intervals for the quantity of interest that is computed from the biased data.  See examples [here](https://fharrell.com/post/hxcontrol).

Answer (score 1):

> Let's also assume that our estimator does not have any access to sampling weights, so we cannot explicitly bias-correct it by re-weighting the observations.

Without data or information about the bias, there is no way to correct for it.

If your good dataset is ~U(-2,2) but nothing tells us how it relates to the original, then how are we supposed to know it came from a population that follows N(0,1) instead of N(1,1)?

> Under what general conditions would we be able to obtain an unbiased estimate?

A neccesary condition is that we can make assumptions about the bias and either compute them theoretically or estimate them based on some data.

If some parameter $\theta$ is what we want to infer with data $X$, then we require a (assumed) model $f(X,\theta)$ for the distribution of observations that describes some  dependence of the data on the parameter $\theta$. Or, otherwise  an empty set would be a sufficient statistic.